# Book Review in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` for my thesis. I have to create some entries for book reviews. But as I know, `biblatex` doesnt provide an entry type specifically for reviews as standard type. It seems that I have to put the reviews in the type `article`. However, one would expect more functionalities than the normal `article`. Like the [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11007-012-9215-z) shows, the informations of a reviewed work should actually contain complete formatting: title in italic etc. But the `article` provides only one formatting for its `title` which seems to contain the informations of reviewed works. Is there a cleverer method for inputting the book reviews than just input them all manually in `article`?

Comment: `biblatex` does have a document type `review`, the standard styles just don't support it. Depending on your needs, `biblatex-fiwi` which has special support for `review` might be of interest.

Comment: I think biblatex-chicago supports this type as well.

Comment: I am using biblatex-philosophy. It has a better layout. But the short documentation of biblatex-philosophy is in Italian. It seems that it doesnt really provide an entrytype review.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to build a short [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including a small `bib` file (use package `filecontents` to include it in the MWE) to play with?

Comment: To answer this properly we need a MWE of the input you want to use and how it should look. Without those, it's too localized.